# Google App Engine Launcher not starting

Tags: python, windows, google-app-engine

I'm install google app engine on my laptop and when i clicked on google app engine launcher icon, mouse change to loading icon then nothing run, nothing display and no error reported, just nothing.

My laptop running with WIN7 64bit, Python27 installed.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I was having same problem with google app engine 1.8.0 then i installed the latest 1.8.1 and the issue fixed!

Comment: My installed version is the lastest.